# How to save value from System.currentTimeMillis() in android studio

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SensorEventListener {

    long start_time;
    int record_state;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    Long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (record_state == 1)
    {
        start_time = time;
        record_state = 0;
    }

    if(Ax.size() == N_SAMPLES && Ay.size() == N_SAMPLES && Az.size() == N_SAMPLES) //assuming this gets executed 
    {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Size of Ax: " + Integer.toString(Ax.size()) +
                    "\nSize of Ay: " + Integer.toString(Ay.size()) +
                    "\nSize of Az: " + Integer.toString(Az.size()) + "\n" + Long.toString((time)) + "\n" + Long.toString((start_time)) + "\nrecord state: " + Integer.toString((record_state)), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

But it appears that `time` and `start_time` always have the same value. I want `start_time` to record the time at the very beginning (or freeze the value of `time` at one instant) only. How can I do this? What is wrong with this code?

Comment: Beginning of what??

Comment: I mean when that piece of code is executed, I want to record the time at that instant

Comment: And what's the problem? Be specific and provide a [mcve].

Comment: Besides `time == 4000` will always be bigger than 4000. Your `Long time = System.currentTimeMillis(); gives  you the milliseconds since January 1970!

Comment: But it seems that the value of `record_state` is not constant, it changes with `time`. No pun intended

Comment: Sorry I will update the code

Comment: I edited the if statement, kindly check

Comment: I think you want to have two separate values which are representing time start_tim and eecution_time then if you compare booth of them and the value will be 4000 then you want to show Toast messge.

Comment: @Robert i edited the if statement,

Comment: I would be surprised if the `Toast` ever gets executed. Your condition `if ((time - start_time) == 4000)` is very specific. You would have to be polling this method every 500 milliseconds to get a differ of exactly 4000. This  >= 4000 would more likely get triggered.

Comment: okay assuming I used that condition, the problem is still there. `start_time` and `time` always have the same instantaneous value

Comment: @Barns I would have asked that in another question, but you already answered it. I actually used a different if statement, which gets executed. I just used this example so it will be more clear to you. Otherwise, I have to provide the entire code.

Comment: They will never be different because they have the same value! @Chaine

Comment: Can I have a workaround so that `start_time` retains the value of `time` at a certain instant only?

Comment: @Chaine :: There is obviously more to your code than you have posted. It would be helpful to know where and how the coded is being called and the complete method you use to calculate time difference and where does "record_state" come from. What is triggering the method call?

Comment: You just have a logical error you will need to say what you want to do so We can redesign your code!!

Comment: @Barns this piece of code is supposed to be inside `onSensorChanged()`

Comment: @Xenolion that's the logic I want to implement, freezing the value of `start_time`

Comment: I might have suspected that the problem is coming from the confusion between `long` and `Long`, as what one answer is suggesting. But how exactly, I do not know.

Comment: But it really doesn't get executed because `(time - start_time == 0)`

Comment: @Chaine :: In your edited code you still have a small issue. Have you tried my solution?

Comment: I am yet to check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the code below does not work as you expected it to, then I suspect, that you have an issue with when and how "record_state" is being set somewhere in your code.

Local values with class wide scope:

```
int record_state = 1;
int iterations = 0;
long start_time;
```

When your `onSensorChanged` triggers call  `checkTimeDiff`

```
private void checkTimeDiff(){
    iterations++;

    long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    if (record_state == 1)
    {
        start_time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        record_state = 0;
    }

    long diff = time - start_time;
    Log.e("My Timer", "Time difference = " + diff + " number of iterations = " + iterations);

    if (diff >= 4000)
    {
        record_start = 1;
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Long.toString(time) + "\n" + Long.toString(start_time), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

It appears as if you are using "record_state" as a digital flag. In that case a boolean would be more elegant. But I will use your code as much as possible.

Comment: Yes, that is right -- Copy and paste has failed me again.

Comment: `start_time` keeps on changing with `time`

Comment: @Chaine :: So `time - start_time` is always equal to Zero?

Comment: @Chaine :: I have add a couple if lines of code which will help you observe what takes place in the method. Please change your code to see what is going on.

Comment: hi barns, I have solved it already. You are absolutely right, I have another assignment for `record_state` as 1 elsewhere in the code, hence, `start_time` always gets assigned the current time since `record_state` is always 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use lowercase 'long'.  You are using objects currently and pointing them both to the same reference, so when you change the value of one it affects the other.

Comment: `long` for `start_time` and `Long` for `time` right?

Comment: @eimmer :: I think you got it! You might want to suggest the to the OP that they should use `System.elapsedRealtime();` to do any time measuring. See Android docs :: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#elapsedRealtime()

Comment: @eimmer the same problem still persists though

Comment: where will I use lower case long?

Answer (score 0):

Because this code is going to be used in `onSensorChanged` (referring to your comments) then the solution should be these variables should be declared and used throughout your class and not in the single method and the problem will disappear so please declare this outside any method as local variables:

```
int record_state = 1;
Long start_time;
```

**Code and logic improvements**

- Use `long` instead of `Long`
- Use `>=` instead of `==` because its too hard to get it exactly equal!

Comment: I have declared `start_time` outside and `time` inside the `onSensorChanged`

Comment: I declared it inside the `MainActivity` but outside `onSensorChanged`

Comment: You have done well But I am talking about `record_state=1` should be a outside too like start time other wise the logic fails! Check my answer edited answer carefully!

Comment: yes `record_state = 1` is outside, it's on `onCreate()`

Comment: Is it okay that I initialized my `record_state` in `onCreate()`?

Comment: It is okay even in declaration as I show you in my answer just write `int record_state = 1;`

Comment: I already did. I feel that it should have worked already. But I don't know what the problem is